# TestNG priority annotation conflicts the sequential execution

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have prioritized the methods for every class in TestNG framework.When i am running the suite. I see the Priority 1 method for each of the class getting triggered first followed by next priority for each of the classes.

i also tried using "preserve-order="true">" in testing.xml but to dismay the issue is as is.

..to elaborate

```
Class A
{@Test(priority =1)
 method A1()
@Test(priority =2)
 method A2}

Class B
{@Test(priority =1)
 method B1()
@Test(priority =2)
 method B2}
```

When the suite is trigerred- Execution sequence is A1, B1, A2 and B2. For a similar scenario in the same project in a different package, i see the execution sequence A1, A2, B1 and B2

Answer (score 0):

Use [dependency](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_dependency_test.htm) option of TestNG to achieve order